# Ruby passing param with datepicker input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to pass a value via a button_to in Rails to the index page, but instead it's calling the POST and creating a new null value in the database instead. What I have is this:

In /app/views/index.html.erb

```
<script>$(function() {
  $("#date").datepicker();
});</script>
<% require 'date' %>
<h1>Listing reports for the week of <%= params[:datepicker] || DateTime.now.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') %></h1>

<%= form_tag reports_path do %>
  <input type="string" id="date" name="date" />
  <%= submit_tag "Select Date", :method => "get" %>
<% end %>
```

In /app/controllers/reports_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @date = params[:date] || DateTime.now.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    @reports = Report.where(:entrydate => Date.strptime(@date, '%m/%d/%Y').beginning_of_week..Date.strptime(@date, '%m/%d/%Y').end_of_week)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @reports }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

In /config/routes.rb

```
  match "reports/*date" => "reports#index"
```

When inputting a date manually such as localhost:3000/reports/10/29/2012, the site works fine.

The main problem is that I don't know how to get the input from the  text field to get sent as param[:date] to the reports/index method in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to reports_path(:date => @date) %>
```

EDITED (using a form):

```
<%= form_tag reports_path do %>
  <input type="string" id="datepicker" name="datepicker"/>
  <%= submit_tag "Select Date" %>
<% end %>
```

Something like this.

Comment: This made it so that the button/link now just refreshes the page, because it's just passing `DateTime.now.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')`. I'm trying to get the string from the input box and pass it via the button.

Comment: When doing that, it still seems to be having the same problem where it's calling the POST create method instead of the index method. I'm not even sure if the string is being passed properly. I tried doing the form and it rerouted to `reports/10171` and created a new empty entry in the database.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can have a button_to inside another form. In older versions of Rails button_to is generating a form, perhaps it's still like that, in that case I think that is the problem.

Comment: I'm using the new submit_tag that MurifoX just posted.